# What is the "reset" command for a git cloned repository?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have downloaded a repository with

```
git clone <address>
```

i have made some modification and have edited some files, now i want to discard everything and just be sure that what i have on the disk is nothing else than the original remote version of the codebase: what is the right command ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the long explanation so that you understand what is going on:

Assuming the remote is called `origin`

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git checkout origin/master
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

What this does is:

1. (Optional if git status says no modified files) Discard *any* modified files on the disk (that's why `reset --hard`)
2. Checkout the remote master branch (note: you will be in a “detatched head” state)
3. Delete the local `master` branch (throwing away all your local changes)
4. Call the current head as the new `master` branch

Now you probably want to do something slightly different... i.e. don't throw away your changes , just put them on another named branch... after all you never know when you'll need them again

```
git checkout -b my-silly-changes
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

That saves your current changes in a new local branch called `my-silly-changes` and then removes the old local branch called `master` and finally recreates it from the remote head.

And here is the explanation for people who think they know what they are doing:

The single command:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Will discard any local changes and re-point the current branch to the most recently fetched state of `origin/master`. This has the exact same effect as the four commands at the start of this answer, but without [looking behind the curtain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWyCCJ6B2WE)

Comment: You should also do a `git clean -xfd` to get rid of all untracked files (build products, etc.)

Comment: The first four commands, while correct, are needlessly verbose. If you are on `master`, just `git reset --hard origin/master` will do the same as the four commands. Still, +1 for mentioning the option of creating a local branch.

Comment: *"I want to discard everything and just be sure that what i have on the disk is nothing else than the original remote version of the codebase"* - The method above seems to leave files on the file system that were not part of the clone, like `configure` scripts that were generated from `configure.ac` with `autoreconf`. Leave it to Git to take a simple task, and make it difficult to impossible.

Comment: Does anyone else feel this should be one simple command and not 4 consecutive commands?

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain you want to discard all files, and *lose* all your modifications (!), you can do:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will reset the state of your local copy of the "master" branch and of your working copy to the last version that you fetched from your upstream (original remote).

Note: This assumes that

- your upstream repository is called "origin" (the default for `git clone`)
- you are working in a clone of the remote `master` branch

If you are working in a branch other than "master" , adjust the command:

```
git reset --hard origin/branch1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed anything, then `git reset --hard` is just enough.

[Here](http://progit.org/2011/07/11/reset.html) is a good resource explaining how git reset with its different modes work (--hard, --mixed and --soft).

**Disclaimer**:

`git reset --hard` is an unsafe operation. It removes any uncomnitted changes from the working tree, and cannot be undone.

Comment: *"I want to discard everything and just be sure that what i have on the disk is nothing else than the original remote version of the codebase"* - The method above seems to leave files on the file system that were not part of the clone, like `configure` scripts that were generated from `configure.ac` with `autoreconf`. Leave it to Git to take a simple task, and make it difficult to impossible.